# How to Allow Only specific Decimal values in a text box in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, decimalformat

I have a textbox called UnitValue which should accept only 3 decimal values, that is 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.

I am using data annotations on "UnitValue" property in my model class to verify the values for integers as below for Eg,

**[RegularExpression("[0]{1}|[1]{1}",ErrorMessage="error")

Public int UnitHead {get;set;}**

Public decimal UnitValue{get;set}
I wanted the similar way to happen for decimal property also. requesting your help on getting this validation done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom validation something like this

```
    public class CustomDecimalValues:ValidationAttribute  
    {  
        public override bool IsValid(object value)  
        {  
            // write your own logic for validation
            var decPlaces = (int)(((decimal)value% 1) * 100); 
            return (0.1<= decPlaces &&  decPlaces <= 0.3);  
        }  
    }
```

then use in model like this

```
[CustomDecimalValues(ErrorMessage = "Allowed decimal values are 0.1,0.2 and 0.3")]  
Public decimal UnitValue{get;set}
```

Please find the complete example using link [Custom Validation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: Thanks @Sain Pradeep. It's almost working, I need to use this for multiple properties in a POCO class, but even if value is empty(non required fields) this method is triggering. Any idea how to overcome this one?

Comment: put if statement to bypass empty values if (value is null){ return true; }